# Definition of Laplace - change of variables

Tags: laplace-transform

[image]

Any hint? I am not really understanding where to start

Comment: Do you know the definition of Laplace transform?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal L \{f(at)\}(s)
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(at) \ \mathrm dt \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-su/a}f(u) \ \mathrm d(u/a) \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-st/a}f(t) \ \mathrm d(t/a) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac1a \int_0^\infty e^{-(s/a)t}f(t) \ \mathrm dt \\
&=& \dfrac1a \mathcal L \{f(t)\}\left(\dfrac sa\right) \\
&=& \dfrac1a F\left(\dfrac sa\right) \\
\end{array}$$

The substitution used is $u=at$, where $\mathrm du = a \ \mathrm dt$.

Comment: can you please explain step 2? This is exactly where I got stuck

Comment: @Heyo Substitution, and then change back to the original variable.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now, thanks a lot, I was on a right track but I messed up on substitution.